# Content select separated, how to have just one?

Tags: php

The code display separated select. I think there is something wrong inside the loop. I must just one where there is all inside.

Do you have any idea where the problem come from ?

Thank.

content element

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '220' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '219' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null
```

now the loop

```
      foreach ($options_array as $key => $option) {
        if ($option['type'] == 'select') {

          if ($option['products_option_value'][$key] !== null) {
            $products_options_content_display .= '<div class="form-group">'; // required or not
            $products_options_content_display .= '<label class="control-label ProductsInfoOptionSelect" for="input-option' . $option['products_option_id'] . '">' . $option['name'] . '</label>';
            $products_options_content_display .= '<select name="products_option_id' . $option['products_option_id'] . '" id="input-option' . $option['products_option_id'] . '" class="form-control">';

            $products_options_content_display .= '<option value="">' . OSCOM::getDef('text_select') . '</option>';
```

//var_dump($option['products_option_value'][$key]);

```
            if (!is_null($option['products_option_value'][$key]['products_option_model'])) {
              $model = $option['products_option_value'][$key]['products_option_model'];
            }

            $products_options_content_display .= '<option value="' . $option['products_option_value'][$key]['products_option_value_id'] . '">' . $model . ' - ' . $option['products_option_value'][$key]['name'];

            if ($option['products_option_value'][$key]['price'] > 0) {
              $products_options_content_display .= $option['products_option_value'][$key]['price_prefix'] . ' ' . $option['products_option_value'][$key]['price'];
            }

            $products_options_content_display .= '</option>';
            $products_options_content_display .= '</select>';
            $products_options_content_display .= ' </div>';
          }
        }
      }
```

you can see the result there : https://jsfiddle.net/wx0gvf6L/

add information

```
var_dump($option['products_option_value'][$key]);

    array (size=13)
      'products_option_value_id' => string '175' (length=3)
      'option_value_id' => string '180' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'M' (length=1)
      'image' => null
      'quantity' => string '100' (length=3)
      'subtract' => string '0' (length=1)
      'price' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
      'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'weight' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      'weight_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'customers_group_id' => string '99' (length=2)
      'products_option_model' => string 'SizeM' (length=5)
      'option_tax_class_id' => string '0' (length=1)
    /home/www/clicshopping_test/boutique/sources/template/Default/modules/modules_products_info/pi_products_info_options_new.php:92:
    array (size=13)
      'products_option_value_id' => string '174' (length=3)
      'option_value_id' => string '179' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'S' (length=1)
      'image' => null
      'quantity' => string '100' (length=3)
      'subtract' => string '0' (length=1)
      'price' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
      'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'weight' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      'weight_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'customers_group_id' => string '99' (length=2)
      'products_option_model' => string 'SizeS' (length=5)
      'option_tax_class_id' => string '0' (length=1)


json format
[
   {
      "products_option_id": "240",
      "option_id": "41",
      "name": "test",
      "type": "select",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "239",
      "option_id": "41",
      "name": "test",
      "type": "select",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "238",
      "option_id": "40",
      "name": "Taille",
      "type": "select",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "237",
      "option_id": "40",
      "name": "Taille",
      "type": "select",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "185",
            "option_value_id": "179",
            "name": "S",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "1.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeS",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "236",
      "option_id": "40",
      "name": "Taille",
      "type": "select",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "185",
            "option_value_id": "179",
            "name": "S",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "1.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeS",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "184",
            "option_value_id": "180",
            "name": "M",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeM",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "235",
      "option_id": "40",
      "name": "Taille",
      "type": "select",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "185",
            "option_value_id": "179",
            "name": "S",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "1.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeS",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "184",
            "option_value_id": "180",
            "name": "M",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeM",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "233",
      "option_id": "38",
      "name": "Couleur",
      "type": "radio",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "185",
            "option_value_id": "179",
            "name": "S",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "1.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeS",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "184",
            "option_value_id": "180",
            "name": "M",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeM",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "232",
      "option_id": "38",
      "name": "Couleur",
      "type": "radio",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "185",
            "option_value_id": "179",
            "name": "S",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "1.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeS",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "184",
            "option_value_id": "180",
            "name": "M",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeM",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "183",
            "option_value_id": "183",
            "name": "bleu",
            "image": "",
            "quantity": "50",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "REF-2",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "231",
      "option_id": "38",
      "name": "Couleur",
      "type": "radio",
      "value": null,
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "185",
            "option_value_id": "179",
            "name": "S",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "1.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeS",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "184",
            "option_value_id": "180",
            "name": "M",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeM",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "183",
            "option_value_id": "183",
            "name": "bleu",
            "image": "",
            "quantity": "50",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "REF-2",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "182",
            "option_value_id": "182",
            "name": "vert",
            "image": "",
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "REF-1",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "products_option_id": "234",
      "option_id": "39",
      "name": "Commentaires",
      "type": "textarea",
      "value": "0",
      "required": null,
      "products_option_value": [
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "187",
            "option_value_id": "184",
            "name": "test2",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "0",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "186",
            "option_value_id": "185",
            "name": "test12",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "20.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "0",
            "products_option_model": "============",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "185",
            "option_value_id": "179",
            "name": "S",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "1.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeS",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "184",
            "option_value_id": "180",
            "name": "M",
            "image": null,
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "SizeM",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "183",
            "option_value_id": "183",
            "name": "bleu",
            "image": "",
            "quantity": "50",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "0.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "REF-2",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         },
         {
            "products_option_value_id": "182",
            "option_value_id": "182",
            "name": "vert",
            "image": "",
            "quantity": "100",
            "subtract": "0",
            "price": "10.0000",
            "price_prefix": "+",
            "weight": "0.00",
            "weight_prefix": "+",
            "customers_group_id": "99",
            "products_option_model": "REF-1",
            "option_tax_class_id": "0"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Please provide a view on the data without the `...`. JSON format would be nice, or what `var_export` generates. Please explain what the desired output would be, as it is not clear what the deepest subarrays for `products_option_value` should render to.

Comment: @trincot. I added informations about products_option_value : look : https://jsfiddle.net/wx0gvf6L/ , you will see the problem. Tk

Comment: If you use var_export, you provide something more usable.  Why not include a html output example?

Comment: You only answered one question (and not in a usable format!). What about my the explanation for where these options should appear in the select list? You have *n* option IDs and for each you have potentially several option values... how should that be rendered?  The fiddle only selects one option value and ignores the others.... on which basis?

Comment: @trincot . On this approach I am lost, I tried some orientation and I don't find solution. below test the code of Progrock, not again but ! look this webste : I try to do that  for option products : https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=42 . I hope it better explanation.

Comment: I will look at this on the condition that you provide sample data in either JSON or `var_export` format, and give the literal HTML you expect to get from that. Please make sure the option values appear in the HTML, because I have no idea what you want with them.

Comment: @trincot : There an example of the code that I want to obtain : https://jsfiddle.net/9wx8cn9z/

Comment: Your input, code and desired output should be present in the question, not behind a link. And please use a usable format (not `var_dump`)

Comment: @trincot. I inserted a json format. see above at the end of document

Answer (score 0):

Something more akin to this:

```
foreach ($options_array as $option) {
    if ($option['type'] == 'select') {
        $out .= '<label>' . $option['name'] . '</label>';
        $out .= '<select name="products_option_id' . $option['products_option_id'] . '" id="input-option' . $option['products_option_id'] . '" class="form-control">';
        $out .= '<option value="">' . OSCOM::getDef('text_select') . '</option>';
        foreach($option['products_option_value'] as $value) {
            $out .= '<option value="' . $value['products_option_value_id'] . '">' . $value['products_option_model'] . ' - ' . $value['name'];
            if ($value['price'] > 0) {
                $out .= $value['price_prefix'] . ' ' . $value['price'];
            }
            $out .= '</option>';
        }
        $out .= '</select>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Tk for your help.
Look your approach : I must have 2 select element test and taille. It's better but not that
https://jsfiddle.net/h2Lnku2L/1/